# Nsdictionary Push details view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview (master/detail) which is being populated by NSDictionary. The masterview displays the list of all keys, now, I would like the detailview (which is also atable) to display the values. e.g. Key 1 in master table, has several values, which I would like to be displayed on the detailview,

This is my tableview

-

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSString *key = [myKeyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [MyDictionaryArray objectForKey:key];

    cell.textLabel.text=key;

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    }
    return cell

    //this gives me a list of all keys which is fine
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    TableViewController *dvc=[[TableViewController alloc] init];


    //this is where I am stuck, I want the details to be pushed to the next tableview   

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES ];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing your detail view controller onto the navigation stack you should pass the dictionary for the currently selected row.

```
NSString *key = [myKeyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [MyDictionaryArray objectForKey:key];

dvc.details = myDictionary;
```

Obviously you'll need to declare a `details` property on your custom `TableViewController` class.